# Quantum chemistry Python package to solve the Coupled-Perturbed Hartree–Fock equations

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, software

Two of the most well-known Python quantum chemistry pakcages, PySCF and Psi4, can solve the Hartree–Fock equations. However, I am interested in finding analytic derivatives of the electron integrals:

$$h_{pq}(R) = \displaystyle\int dx \phi_p(x)^{*} \left( -\frac{\nabla_r^2}{2} - \displaystyle\sum_{I} \frac{Z_I}{|r - R_I|} \right) \phi_q(x)$$

$$h_{pqrs}(R) = \displaystyle\int dx_1 dx_2 \frac{\phi_p(x_1)^{*} \phi_q(x_2)^{*} \phi_r(x_2) \phi_s(x_1)}{|r_1 - r_2|}$$

with respect to the nuclear coordinates. To do this, one must solve the **coupled-perturbed Hartree–Fock equations**. It doesn't seem like Psi4 and PySCF have this functionality, so I was wondering if there was any other package I can use to do this?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Chemistry! I see you've already participated on Matter Modelling, so you'll be aware that this question would also fit there. That doesn't mean it's off-topic here, it's perfectly fine; but in the event that you ever want to move it there, feel free to let us know. (But please don't double-post on both sites.)

Comment: Just checking the obvious: What order derivatives do you want? If it's only first order you don't need a CPHF solver.

Comment: [Related question](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/6163/computing-analytic-derivatives-of-molecular-hamiltonians-obtained-from-solving-h) on Matter Modeling. As mentioned there, any program that can do geometry optimizations probably has a way of generating the gradient/hessian (or at least relevant matrix-vector products that are needed for the optimization). So I suspect Psi4 and PySCF have these quantities, its just a matter of it they provide an interface to access them.

Comment: @IanBush First and second order. What can I do other than CPHF to get the first-order derivatives?

Comment: @Tyberius Thanks, the thing that I'm interested in isn't just getting the Hessian of energy gradients, but rather the derivatives of the Hamiltonian itself.

Comment: @JackCeroni But I mean if these programs computing the geometric Hessian of energy analytically, they would need the 1st and 2nd derivatives of these integrals as part of that process.

Comment: Are these packages calculating the gradients/Hessian analytically? I thought that it was done with finite difference.

Comment: @JackCeroni For first order there's a standard trick involving differentiating the orthonormality relation to relate changes in the coefficients to changes in the overlap matrix. Any good book on quantum chemistry should cover it, for instance section 3 in appendix C of Szabo and Ostlund. Also see https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/89831/analytical-gradient-of-the-hartree-fock-nuclear-electronic-repulsion-term

Comment: Thanks! And as for the second order derivatives, I assume there is no “trick”?

Comment: Yes, for second order or greater you need a CPHF solver of appropriate order.

Comment: I see, and do you know of any quantum chemistry packages that have such solvers implemented?

Comment: I'm a co-author of CRYSTAL (https://www.crystal.unito.it/index.php) which has one, but it's not open source. Most large scale packages will have something. Anyway, bed time.

Comment: Are you looking for only python based softwares? And do you need only the hessian matrix (i.e. force constat matrix for atoms) or do you also need the values of the derivatives of electron integrals calculated to get the hessian? (What I am asking is—do you need just the end result or also the intermediate steps?)

Comment: Python-based software would be ideal, but anything that gives me the derivatives I'm looking for works (for instance, something like GAMESS). As for the second point, I'm looking for the derivatives of the electron integrals, not the Hessian itself. Specifically, I'm doing a research project, involving new methods of computing the Hessian, and one of the things I require is the first and second derivatives of these integrals.

Comment: I think a lot of electronic structure software packages will have what you need, but since people don't typically ask for derivatives of the electron integrals individually (they just want the end result, like the Hessian or the geometry optimization), the codes won't let you output these by default. You might have to go into the code and add some `print` statements. I also think you should consider the worth of working on new methods to calculate the Hessian, because quantum chemistry has been around for a century and people have been working on ways to calculate Hessians for about as long.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you @user1271772. There definitely must be these capabilities in quantum chemistry packages, but I've done some digging (jn PySCF, in particular), and can't seem to locate the specific part of the code where these derivatives are calculated. Do you have any suggestions on how to find this functionality?

Comment: I typically use the `grep` function. I think it's doable, but the effort-to-value ratio is immense. Someone may help you with this if the Bounty is large enough. Quantum chemistry codes involve millions of lines. In PySCF, Qiming Sun alone has [added content to 1.5 million lines and removed content from 1.6 million lines](https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/graphs/contributors). Be very careful about quantum computing projects, especially ones that involve quantum chemistry.

Comment: Related: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/3787/5

Answer (score 4):

As many of the comments here and on your [question at MMSE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6163/5) suggest, pretty much all major electronic structure software can solve the "coupled-perturbed Hartree–Fock equations" as [Ian's comment](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/153218/quantum-chemistry-python-package-to-solve-the-coupled-perturbed-hartree-fock-equ#comment313949_153218) points out that it's needed for the second derivatives, and most (if not all) mainstream electronic structure packages use the Hessian matrix (involving the second derivatives) to do geometry optimization.

- Ian Bush [mentioned here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/153218/quantum-chemistry-python-package-to-solve-the-coupled-perturbed-hartree-fock-equ#comment313951_153218) that [CRYSTAL](https://www.crystal.unito.it/index.php) can do it, but is not open source.
- My comment [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/6163/computing-analytic-derivatives-of-molecular-hamiltonians-obtained-from-solving-h/6267?noredirect=1#comment12305_6163) mentioned that [OpenMOLCAS](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/acs.jctc.9b00532) can do it.
- Susi Lehtola's answer [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/6267/5) mentioned that PySCF and Psi4 can both do it, and that [Psi4 allows you to print out the Hessian matrix by default (i.e. without adding your own `print` statements)](https://psicode.org/psi4manual/master/freq.html) and that the `libcint` library that PySCF users, or the `libint` library that Psi4 uses, can offer you the derivative integrals that you want.
- The fact that the above "constellation" of software packages all offer this functionality, makes me convinced that all major electronic structure programs can calculate those derivative integrals and solve the CPHF equations (though the ease of accessing them may vary).